# How to use TCP Keepalive with Endpoints in Twisted?

Tags: python, tcp, twisted

Twisted does support [TCP Keepalive](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/api/twisted.internet.tcp.Connection.html#setTcpKeepAlive). But I can't find a simple way to set those on endpoints (client and server).

What is the best current practice for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see a way that you can achieve this from endpoints cleanly via the API. However take a look at the source to [`twisted.internet.endpoints._WrappingProtocol`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-13.2.0/twisted/internet/endpoints.py#L67) - you could possibly set your endpoint to use a `_WrappingFactory`* which callbacks a deferred when the connection is made. At this point transport is set on the protocol and you can call `setTcpKeepAlive`.

Given the underscore in the class name, I would say these are meant to be used internally and I wouldn't depend on their interface being consistent between releases. You should use them as a guide.

Alternatively, just call `self.transport.setTcpKeepAlive` in `connectionMade` of your Protocol and handle the case where this is not supported (i.e. where the protocol is used over another transport).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# based on example at http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2008-June/017836.html
from twisted.internet import protocol 
from twisted.internet import reactor

class EchoProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Client Connected Detected!"
        ### enable keepalive if supported
        try:
            self.transport.setTcpKeepAlive(1)
        except AttributeError: pass

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "Client Connection Lost!"

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)


factory = protocol.Factory()
factory.protocol = EchoProtocol 
reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory) 
reactor.run()
```

For this simple example I feel that this gives a fairly clean solution, however there are probably situations where the additional wrapper code is warranted.

* Note that `_WrappingFactory` subclasses `ClientFactory` and may not be suitable for servers.

Comment: I have specifially asked for endpoints. I want a generic solution for any protocol factory.

Comment: Not every transport underlying an endpoint has TCP specific features like "keep alive" or "no delay" .. e.g. Unix domain sockets, serial connections and pipes don't have those.

Comment: @oberstet: That's why I want to do this on the endpoint. A TCP endpoint surely has tcp keepalive. Doing it on the protocol (like suggested in the answer) feels wrong exactly for your reason: One might want to run the EchoProtocol over rs232.

Comment: What should be the effect of setting "keep alive" on an endpoint that runs over serial? It does not make sense ..

Comment: It should error out, of course. You can call the "low level" setTcpKeealive() also only on tcp connections.

Comment: @Elrond, I've looked into this more and I can't see a way that you can achieve this from the endpoint cleanly via the API. However take a look at the source to `twisted.internet.endpoints._WrappingProtocol` - you could possibly set your endpoint to use a `_WrappingFactory` which callbacks a deferred when the connection is made. At this point transport is set on the protocol and you can call `setTcpKeepAlive`. Otherwise, just wrap setTcpKeepAlive in a try except block...

Comment: @PeterGibson: Thanks for investigating and confirming my own findings, that I will need to write/reuse like three wrappers for clients and servers (1. wrap the endpoint, obviously, 2. wrap the Factory, 3. wrap the protocol).  Could you please turn your comment into an actual answer?