# How to enable SSH ServerAlive and ClientAlive in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.conch

I have a problem with an ungraceful disconnect, similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903574/twisted-unexpected-connection-lost). The proposed TCPKeepAlive solution is too slow. As I work with the SSH protocol, I have been wondering whether it is possible to enable/easily implement in Twisted the SSH *ServerAlive* and *ClientAlive* functions and define short intervals (~5s) after which *connectionLost* would be called.